# Print wont print after elif statment

Tags: python

So I am trying to make a cowboy game (double 07) in python. I have the first elif statement working just fine but the other two aren't working. There are more to come but I want to sort the errors out so I don't continue doing them.

```
import sys
import os
import time
import random
import colorama
from colorama import Fore
import random


#cool typing effect
from sys import stdout as s
from time import sleep as j
def w(print):
  for i in print:
    j(.03)
    s.write(i)
    s.flush()
  next = input()
def noinput(print):
  for i in print:
    j(.03)
    s.write(i)
    s.flush()



#main code for the game hub   


def guess_the_number():
  os.system('clear')
  num = random.randint(1, 50)
  guess = "none"


  while guess != num:
    guess = input(Fore.CYAN + "Choose a number: ")
    guess = int(guess)

    if guess == num:
      w(Fore.GREEN + "You guessed the correct number!")
      os.system('clear')
    else:
      w(Fore.RED + "Sorry try again")
      print(Fore.WHITE + "------------")

      if guess > num:
        w("your number is too large")
        os.system('clear')
      else:
        w("your number is too small")
        os.system('clear')

def rock_paper_scissors():
  os.system('clear')
  user_action = input(Fore.BLUE + "Pick your item (rock, paper, scissors): ")
  w(Fore.WHITE + "you chose: " + user_action)
  computer_choice = ["scissors", "paper", "rock"]
  computer_choice = random.choice(computer_choice)
  w(Fore.WHITE + "computer chose: " + computer_choice)
  if user_action == computer_choice:
    w(Fore.BLUE + f"Both players chose {user_action} its a tie!")


  elif user_action == "rock":
    if computer_choice == "scissors":
      w(Fore.GREEN + "Player wins! Rock destroys Scissors.")
    else:
      w(Fore.RED + "Paper covers Rock! Computer wins.")

  elif user_action == "paper":
    if computer_choice == "rock":
      w(Fore.GREEN + "Player wins! Paper covers Rock.")
    else:
      w(Fore.RED + "Scissors cut Paper! Computer wins.")

  elif user_action == "scissors":
    if computer_choice == "paper":
      w(Fore.GREEN + "Player wins! Scissors cut Paper.")
    else:
      w(Fore.RED + "Rock destroys Scissors! Computer wins.")
      os.system('clear')
  play_again = input(Fore.CYAN + "Play again? y/n: ")
  if play_again == ("y"):
    os.system('clear')
    rock_paper_scissors()

  else:
    os.system('clear')
    choices()
```

The error is in this game

```
def cowboy_game():
  os.system('clear')

  #----cowboy game code-------
  user_action = input("pick your move: ")
  os.system('clear')

  computer_choice = ["shoot", "reload", "guard"]
  computer_choice = random.choice(computer_choice)
  w("player chose: " + str(user_action))
  w("computer chose: " + str(computer_choice))
  #random if statement so elif will work since python is retarded in that way
  fgf = print("")
  if fgf == ("f"):
    print("")

  elif user_action == "shoot":
    if computer_choice == "shoot":
      print(Fore.WHITE + "Both Players killed each other. ")
      time.sleep(0.5)
      play_again = input("Play again? y/n: ")
      if play_again == ("y"):
        cowboy_game()
        os.system('clear')
      if play_again == ("n"):
        choices()
        os.system('clear')
```

It prints the statement above

```
  elif user_action == "shoot":
    if computer_choice == "reload":
      print(Fore.WHITE + "Player killed enemy.")
      time.sleep(0.5)
      play_again = input("Play again? y/n: ")
      if play_again == ("y"):
        cowboy_game()
        os.system('clear')
      if play_again == ("n"):
        choices()
        os.system('clear')

  
  elif user_action == "shoot":
    if computer_choice == "guard":
      print(Fore.WHITE + "Enemy blocked the bullet. No damage.")
      cowboy_game()
      os.system('clear')
```

It doesn't print at all for those statments

```
w(Fore.WHITE + "Welcome to my game hub! Pick a number to start ")
os.system('clear')
print("----------")

def choices():
  print(Fore.CYAN + "1) Rock Paper Scissors")
  print(Fore.WHITE + "----------")
  print(Fore.CYAN + "2) Guess the number")
  print(Fore.WHITE + "----------")
  print(Fore.CYAN + "3) Cowboy game")
  print(Fore.WHITE + "---------")

choices()
choice = input("Choice: ")

if choice == ('1'):
  os.system('clear')
  w("Everyone knows how to play this. Have fun!")
  rock_paper_scissors()


if choice == ('2'):
  os.system('clear')
  w("Welcome to Guess the Number! Try and guess the number to play")
  guess_the_number()

if choice == ('3'):
  os.system('clear')
  w("--(Welcome to cowboy! Instructions in the next line)--")
  os.system('clear')
  w("To shoot you need to reload first. choices: reload, guard, or shoot. What these do 
  are self explanatory lol")

  w(Fore.CYAN + "press enter to start the game")
  os.system('clear')
  w(Fore.BLUE + "have fun! :)")
  os.system('clear')
  cowboy_game()
```

I cannot find anything online to help with this so I'm going to leave it up to the users on this site.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question it should have no more code than the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem by copy-pasting, a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions for the Elif statements are the same.
try:

```
elif user_action == "shoot":
    if computer_choice == "shoot":
      print(Fore.WHITE + "Both Players killed each other. ")
      time.sleep(0.5)
      play_again = input("Play again? y/n: ")
      if play_again == ("y"):
        cowboy_game()
        os.system('clear')
      if play_again == ("n"):
        choices()
        os.system('clear')
   
   elif computer_choice == "reload":
      print(Fore.WHITE + "Player killed enemy.")
      time.sleep(0.5)
      play_again = input("Play again? y/n: ")
      if play_again == ("y"):
        cowboy_game()
        os.system('clear')
      if play_again == ("n"):
        choices()
        os.system('clear')

    elif computer_choice == "guard":
      print(Fore.WHITE + "Enemy blocked the bullet. No damage.")
      cowboy_game()
      os.system('clear')

elif user_action == "reload":
   (rest of your edge cases)
```